# How do I make this more efficient matching input from file within a given range

Tags: python, file, tkinter, range, python-itertools

I have created a username and password program using GUI and I wanted to ensure that if the user enters any of the correct usernames or any of the correct passwords from 2 different files then display 'you have accessed something.' However, I am not sure how to do this, Thank you. It will not work, currently. This is a section of my program:

```
def reveal(self):
    file=open('username.txt','r')
    data1=file.readlines()
    file.close

    file1=open('username.txt','r')
    data2=file1.readlines()
    file1.close

    content2=self.username.get()
    content=self.password.get()


    if content2==(data1[0,3].replace("\n","")) and content==(data2[0,3].replace("\n","")): 
        message='You have access to something special.'

    else:
        message='Access denied.'

    self.text.delete(0.0,END)
    self.text.insert(0.0,message)
```

I also tried this, however it still does not work:

```
def reveal(self):
    import itertools

    file1=open('username.txt','r')
    data1=file1.readlines()
    file1.close


    file=open('password.txt','r')
    data2=file.readlines()
    file.close

    content2=self.username.get()
    content=self.password.get()
    with open(username, "r") as file1 , open(password, "r") as file :
        if content2 ==itertools.islice(file1,0, 3) and content==itertools.islice(file,0, 3):

            message='you have access to something'


        else:
            message='Access denied.'
```

I want this program to be able to use multiple usernames and passwords from each of the files, whilst ensuring that only data[0] from the username file matches up with data2[0] from the password file.

Latest version:

```
def reveal(self):
    file=open('username1.txt','r')
    data1 =file.read()
    file.close()

    file1=open('password1.txt','r')
    data2 =file1.read()
    file1.close()

    content2=self.username.get()
    content=self.password.get()


    data1 = data1.split("\n")
    data2 = data2.split("\n")
    for i in range(len(data1)):
        if data1[i] == content2 and data2[i] == content:
            message = 'You have access to something special.'
            break

        else:
            message='Access denied.'

    self.text.delete(0.0,END)
    self.text.insert(0.0,message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with

> `data1[0,3].replace("\n","")`

and

> `(data2[0,3].replace("\n","")`

If I understand you correctly, there are multiple passwords and usernames in each of their files, and any password can be used with any username?

If so, then you want to do this:

```
if content2 in data1.split("\n") and content in data2.split("\n"):
    message = "You have access to something special."
```

Note you will need to change `file1.readlines()` and `file.readlines()` to `file1.read()` and `file.read()` for this to work, or simply take the `\n` off the end of each line with something like:

`data1 = [i[:-1] for i in file.readlines()]`

and

`data2 = [i[:-1] for i in file1.readlines()]`

EDIT:
In order to make it so the first must match the first etc. you can do this:

```
data1 = data1.split("\n")
data2 = data2.split("\n")
for i in range(len(data1)):
    if data1[i] == content2 and data2[i] == content:
        message = "You have access to something special."
        break
```

Comment: @TheCompStudentAJ I have added an edit and remember to substitute .readlines() for .read()

Comment: It displays access denied when I add the edited code

Comment: Note that this code should be instead of the earlier code. Are each of your usernames and passwords on new lines in their files?

Comment: Yes i have replaced this to the earlier code and my usernames and passwords are on new lines

Comment: I’m not sure whether this is the problem, but you should have () after file.close and file1.close as they’re functions.

Comment: You may want to print the values of content and content2 to check that they are what you think they should be.

Comment: `file=open('username1.txt','r')                                                                   
        data1 =file.read()
        file.close()

        file1=open('password1.txt','r') 
        data2 =file1.read()  
        file1.close () 

        content2=self.username.get()
        content=self.password.get()  `

        
        then the edited code below it

Comment: I’d advise you print all of your variables (content, data1, etc.) and check that they are what they should be. Check that the username and password you’re using for testing are in the same positions in their lists, and that they are equal to the values of content and content2.

Comment: printed content and content2 and they are correct but still displays access denied

Comment: And are they both in data1 and data2 and in the same positions?

Comment: Oh, if you have an else in there, place a break after the message = “You have access”.

Comment: By that, do you mean that only the one set works, and the others don’t? Make sure the break is still within the if statement.

Comment: I got the username and the password mixed up sorry it works thank you

Comment: Okay, I’m glad it worked. I must admit I was getting a bit worried there. My entire understanding of python was crumbling around me.